# Block causing Segmentation fault?

Tags: segmentation-fault, c++14

Please help me locate the block causing this fault because the online site I'm using doesn't accept my code. This is the input the site has given to me.

input:

```
2
3 0
110
6 1
101100
```

```cpp
int main() {
  int *T = NULL, *N = NULL, K = 0;
  int temp = 0, counter = 0;
  char bit = '0';
  string str = "";
  T = new int;
  N = new int;
  cin >> *T;
  for (int i = 0; i < *T; i++) {
  start:
    cin >> *N >> K;
    if ((*N < 1 || *N > 1000)) goto start;
    char S[*N + 1];
    cin >> S;
    while (K != 0) {
      if (S[counter] != S[*N - (1 + counter)]) {
        if (S[counter] == bit)
          S[counter] = '1';
        else
          S[counter] = '0';
      }

      str = S;
      for (int j = 0; j < (*N / 2); j++) {
        if (j != (*N / 2)) {
          temp = str[j];
          str[j] = str[*N - (1 + j)];
          str[*N - (1 + j)] = temp;
        }
      }
      if (str == S) break;
      K--;
      counter++;
      if (counter == *N) break;
    }
    if (str == S)
      cout << "Yes" << endl;
    else
      cout << "No" << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce any segmentation fault ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Mv4c8ojKG)). Can you provide more info about where you are getting it?

Comment: you mean the site or the part in the code where I think could be issue?

Comment: On my IDE there is not SEGSIV error but on code chef I get the error

Comment: `counter` is not reset to 0 between tests. The next test would start with `counter` as it was left over by the previous test. It's then possible that `S[counter]` would access out of bounds.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you that's logically correct what you just said.